# Calling function on dynamic page in aspx code behind

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a function `loadList()` that loads a dynamic list based on our database.

In `element_maint.aspx.vb`:

```
Private Sub loadList()
    'load sub-organizations
    Dim lstItems As cihElementList = Nothing

    Dim thr As TableHeaderRow = Nothing
    Dim tr As TableRow = Nothing
    Dim tc As TableCell = Nothing
    Dim lnk1 As HyperLink = Nothing
    Dim lnk2 As HyperLink = Nothing

    Dim item As cihCategoryOrgDef = Nothing

    Dim rvd As Routing.RouteValueDictionary = Nothing
    Dim rvdDeactivate As Routing.RouteValueDictionary = Nothing
    Dim vpd As Routing.VirtualPathData = Nothing
    Dim vpdDeactivate As Routing.VirtualPathData = Nothing

    Dim btnAction As cihBootstrapButtonDropdown = Nothing

        '*****************************************
        'Build the action drop down
        'Build the action button
        '*****************************************
        btnAction = New cihBootstrapButtonDropdown("Action", cihBootstrapButtonDropdown.buttonTypes.link)

        'Existing Items
        lstItems = New cihElementList()
        lstItems.loadForOrganization(orgId)

        For Each ele As cihElementList.elementShort In lstItems.listOfElements
            tr = New TableRow

            lnk1 = New HyperLink
            lnk1.Text = "Edit"
            lnk2 = New HyperLink
            lnk2.Text = "Deactivate"

            rvd = New Routing.RouteValueDictionary(New With {.action = "edit", .elementid = ele.elementId.ToString()})
            rvdDeactivate = New Routing.RouteValueDictionary(New With {.action = "deactivate", .elementid = ele.elementId.ToString()})
            vpd = Routing.RouteTable.Routes.GetVirtualPath(Nothing, "element_maint", rvd)
            vpdDeactivate = Routing.RouteTable.Routes.GetVirtualPath(Nothing, "element_deactivate", rvdDeactivate)


            btnAction.addLink("Edit", vpd.VirtualPath, False)

            If (ZenCommon.CurrentUser.secLevelId = cihCommonDef.FullSiteAdmin Or ZenCommon.CurrentUser.secLevelId = cihCommonDef.OrganizationAdmin) Then 'if SuperAdmin or Campus Admin
                'Need Help here
                btnAction.addLink("Deactivate", vpdDeactivate.VirtualPath, False) 
            End If

            ZenCommon.AddCell(tr, ele.eleDescr, , , "200px")

            tc = New TableCell
            tc.Controls.Add(New LiteralControl(btnAction.buttonHTML))
            tc.Style.Add("width", "50px")

            tr.Cells.Add(tc)

            Me.tblList.Rows.Add(tr)
        Next

End Sub


Private Sub deactivateTag()
       'Goto Database, flag 'tag' as inactive
End Sub
```

I want the btnAction.addLink("Deactivate")  to call a function in my aspx.vb. The function will go mark the tag as inactive.

Right now the 'Edit" button (just above the 'Deactivate' button, will go to a new page to allow you to edit it. I get that. But is there a way to make it so when I click my 'Deactivate' button it will just call my `deactivateTag()`

Answer (score 1):

In your codebehind you could change your method signature

```
Protected Sub deactivateTag(ByRef sender as Object, ByRef e as System.EventArgs) Handles btnDeactivate.Click
```

and in your markup

```
<asp:Button ID="btnDeactivate" onClick="deactivateTag" />
```

Or you can add a click event for the button and call your function from that event.

```
 Protected Sub btnDeactivate_Click(ByRef sender as Object, ByRef e as System.EventArgs) Handles btnDeactivate.Click
 deactivateTag()
End Sub
```

It depends on whether you'll need to call deactivateTag from other controls or not.